# How to calculate the correlation between smoking patients and heart attacks for each country?

Tags: r, correlation, count-data, contingency-tables, association-measure

I have a set of data on smoking patients and heart attack on different time points for 25 countries.

How can I calculate the correlation between the smoking patients and heart attacks for each country?

My data look like this table[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxEh2.png):

```
         Smoking             Heart Attack
Country  1988  1984  2010    1988  1984  2010
-------  ----  ----  ----    ----  ----  ----
Congo    1200  1146   675     900   400   550
Nigeria  1100   786   765     950   568   590
Zimbabwe 1098   897   900    1098   769   865
...
```

I am looking for a solution in R.

Comment: Have you looked into the `cor()` function?

Comment: I want the correlation for each country.

Comment: That is not the correlation, but if you want to check the hypothesis that smoking and heart attacks are not independent for different countries, have a look at `mosaic` plots.

Comment: Are the years there to define the pairing of the counts for smokers and heart attacks?

Comment: @Michael: not really they are just data of smokers and the heart patients in that country at particular times. so if you want you may eliminate the time points.

Comment: If I understand it correctly that you are pairing by year then for each country you only have three pairs to use to compute the correlation for each country. So am I right in thinking that you want to calculate 25 correlations, one for each country?

Comment: Michael: Yes, exactly. I want to have 25 correlations one for each country

Comment: My question was whether or not the year was used for pairing, that is for Congo there are 1200 smokers for 1988 and 900 heart attack cases in 1988. so (1200, 900) is taken as one of the three pairs used to calculate the correlation.  Are there only the 3 years shown in the table?

Comment: Micheal: sorry for late reply. What I have is this dataset and I want to compute the correlation of smokers with heart attack cases for each country. I don't know whether taking time frame into account will help or can we compute it as a whole taking total number of smokers & cases of heart attack for a country and then computing it. Let me put it other way, if you had this dataset and you had to give the correlation for each country what method you had adopted and why. I need guidiance and help in computing this. Thank you.

Comment: @Angelo Computing correlation requires pairing data.  The correlation measures the degree to which a change in number of smokers changes the number of heart attacks in a linear fashion.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but perhaps preempts another. Just because (suppose) that high levels of smoking are correlated with high levels of heart attacks, that *does not* mean that smokers are more likely to have heart attacks. Such an interpretation would be a version of the [ecological fallacy](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~census/549.pdf).

Comment: Good point, @Charlie.  I'll only quibble with your wording for the sake of future readers (I'm sure you're aware of the following).  Correct use of "correlation" requires that we take into account all levels of each variable.  It would have been correct to say "(suppose) that levels of smoking are correlated with levels of heart attacks...."  Limiting the statement to just the high levels is problematic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is best to get the data into a normalized form where `smoking` and `heart attack` are separate, parallel columns and other columns provide the identifying (key) fields:

```
    country  year   smoking heart
1   Congo    1988      1200   900
2   Congo    1984      1146   400
3   Congo    2010       675   550
4   Nigeria  1988      1100   950
5   Nigeria  1984       786   568
6   Nigeria  2010       765   590
7   Zimbabwe 1988      1098  1098
8   Zimbabwe 1984       897   769
9   Zimbabwe 2010       900   865
```

In `R` they ought to be in a data frame:

```
data <- data.frame(country=c(rep("Congo", 3), rep("Nigeria", 3), rep("Zimbabwe", 3)),
                   year=rep(c(1988, 1984, 2010), 3),
                   smoking=c(1200, 1146, 675, 1100, 786, 765, 1098, 897, 900),
                   heart=c(900,400, 550, 950, 568, 590, 1098, 769, 865))
```

**With this format, the solution is a one-liner:**

```
by(data, data$country, function(x) cor(x$smoking, x$heart))
```

The output gives correlations of 0.315, 0.994, and 0.962 for Congo, Nigeria, and Zimbabwe, respectively.

However, **correlations by themselves can be misleading.**  It is far better to *look* at the data:

```
plot(data$smoking, data$heart, col=data$country, pch=19,
 main="Heart attack and smoking, 1984-2010", xlab="Smoking", ylab="Heart attacks")
points(data$smoking, data$heart, cex=1.25)
legend(675, 1075,  levels(data$country), pch=19, col=1:length(levels(data$country)))
```

[image: Scatterplot]

An outlying value for Congo visible in the lower right at (1146, 400) is responsible for its low correlation coefficient: the correlation is a poor description of the smoking-heart attack relation for this country's data.

Comment: +1 very nice argument from looking at a scatter plot of the data.  You remind us of the importance of scatter plots and graphics in general that should be the first step in the analysis process before any models are fit to the data!

Comment: Based on this very nice answer I have made a substantial addition to my answer which discusses the issue of the 1982 data point from the Congo that you found to be an important outlier.  Please take a look.

Comment: @whuber: Beautifully done and very helpful to this R neophyte.

Answer (score 1):

The correlation coefficient between two variables X and Y is just Cov(X,Y)/[√Var(X)√Var(Y)]
and

Cov(X,Y) = E[(X-m$_1$)(Y-m$_2$)] where m$_1$ and m$_2$ are the respective means for X and Y. Given paired observations (X$_i$,Y$_i$) for i=1,2,..,n

Cov(X,Y) is estimated by

∑ (X$_i$-m$_1$$_b$) (Yi-m$_2$$_b$)/n where m$_1$$_b$ = ∑X$_i$/n  and m$_2$$_b$=∑Y$_i$/n.

The estimate for Var(X) is usually ∑ (X$_i$-m$_1$$_b$)$^2$/(n-1) and the estimate of

Var(Y) = ∑ (Y$_i$-m$_2$$_b$)$^2$/(n-1).

This tells you how to calculate the correlation coefficient.  So you could write your own R code to do this.  But first you need to know which Y goes with X.  So you need to have the data paired.  It seems that you logically would pair based on taking them from the same year.  So for example the correlation coefficient for the Congo would be
the estimated covariance:

{(1200-1007)(900-616.7) + (1146-1007)(400-616.7) + (675-1007) (550-616.7)}/3  divided by

[√{((1200-1007)$^2$ + (1146-1007)$^2$ +(675-1007)$^2$)/2} √{(900-616.7)$^2$ + (400-616.7)$^2$ +(550-616.7)$^2$}/2

The numbers 1007 and 616.7 appear in the formula because they represent m$_1$$_b$ and m$_2$$_b$ respectively.

Given Bill Huber's display of the data it is clear that the Congo does not follow the regression line that seems to fit well to the other countries because of one outlier in 1984.  It is so extreme that it is an obvious problem based on the scatter plot.  This may mean that there must be some strange reason why the high smoking rate in the Congo in 1984 does not lead to a high incidence of heart attacks in 1984 or that there is a recording error.  Both possibilities should be looked into.

Looking at the other two points we see a low rate of heart attacks in 2010 and a corresponding reduction in smoking over the high rates in the 1980s and a high rate of heart attacks in 1988 associated with a high rate of smoking.  This leads me to conjecture that either (1) heart attack awarness was not great in 1984 and so cases went unreported and that increased awareness between 1984 and 1988 led to better reporting and a higher rate.  It seems this awareness may have led to decline in smoking in the Congo by 2010, or (2) a correct and consistent number of heart attacks occurred in 1984 but there was a data entry error on that number or (3) the much less plausible explanation that the low heart attack rate was correct but the high smoking rate was a recording error in 1984.  I think (3) is doubtful because the smoking rate in 1988 is close to the recorded value for 1984 and it seems less credible that smoking rates would go up dramatically between 1984 and 1988. Nevertheless these three scenarios could explain the problem and there may be other plausible explanations that ideally should be investigated.

It is important to recognize that the 1984 outlier should not be ignored.  Points like this tend to dramatically effect the correlation estimate (lowering it) as well as the variances (increasing them in this cas).  In this case the outlier is noticeable without looking at multivariate outlier detection methods.

In my 1982 paper which came out of this ORNL technical report [here](http://www.osti.gov/energycitations/product.biblio.jsp?osti_id=6243468) which I have referenced on stackexchange [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32941/examples-of-lurking-variable-and-influential-observation) shows how to calculate the influence function for the sample correlation at points in the (x,y) plane.  In less obvious cases this could be helpful in identifying such outliers.