# Reference for flawed randomized controlled trial

Tags: references, experiment-design, teaching, random-allocation

For a seminar, I am preparing an overview of advantages and shortcomings of randomized control trials (RCT; one shortcoming is, for example, often a limited external validity).

To illustrate potential problems with RCTs, I would like to give [some examples](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74262/what-examples-of-lurking-variables-in-controlled-experiments-are-there-in-public) of what can go wrong during the implementation of a randomized control design. I remember once being told about the following story of a flawed randomized controlled trial. It goes roughly as follows (I do not remember it exactly):

> In the early days of the development of HIV drugs, an AIDS diagnosis
>   often meant an agonizing death. Patients were accordingly in despair.
>   At one point there was a promising drug (which later was shown to have
>   indeed some beneficial effects). This drug was tested for efficacy
>   against a placebo in a double blinded randomized trial. There were
>   no obvious flaws in the randomization protocol or how it was
>   implemented. The results of the initial trials were however a rather
>   precise zero effect. How this could be the case?

The answer is the following (or similar to that):

> Patients had to show up repeatedly to receive the treatment or
>   placebo. Patients obviously did not know whether they are in the
>   treatment or the control group. They just knew what the treatment pill
>   could perhaps save or prolong their life. So they took their chance:
>   After receiving the pills, all participants met. In order to ensure
>   that they receive the treatment pill (on average) at least half of the
>   time, they throw all pills into a basket and mixed them again.

I hope I remember this example correctly. I think this is an interesting story about what can go wrong with randomization protocols. However, I cannot find any reference confirming this story!

Could anyone provide me with a source (ideally including further information)?

Are there other similar examples?

Comment: The example you give is a very interesting story! However, I'm not sure it's an issue with RCT's, but rather an issue with patients **breaking** the randomized part of the RCT.

Comment: In theory, the major issue with RCT's is that they are a very slow and expensive way to collect information. This can be a barrier to getting effective treatments to the market. Unfortunately, it's really hard to find a story "Treatment X *should* have saved one million lives, but the company couldn't afford to test it".

Comment: You are right with the fact that undermine the randomization in this example but this is in my view a potential shortcoming with RCTs: you have only on paper full control about what is going on and how humans behave in or outside the lab.

Comment: "Limited external validity" is often misunderstood.  See https://fharrell.com/rct-mimic which discusses why this is less of a problem than it appears.

Comment: @FrankHarrell the link unfortunately does not work on my computer (404 Page not found)

Comment: Very sorry - should be https://fharrell.com/post/rct-mimic